# Unreadable tag "sqlservermanagementstudio"

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I just noticed a question with what I first thought was a newly create tag and opened it up with the intention of fixing the tag. However, that tag has already been used 80 times.

The tag in question is "sqlservermanagementstudio".

Can someone with suitable powers please add some dashes in there so that it doesn't look like a Welsh town name?

Comment: Nah, [THIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch) is a *proper* Welsh town name :-)

Comment: @Ben, all we're missing is half a dozen or so ells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created the MSSQL-SSMS tag, merged sqlservermanagementstudio into it, and set sqlservermanagementstudio to be a synonym of MSSQL-SSMS

Comment: Much better. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Might not be able to. It seems there is a length limit of 25 characters for a tag name. Adding a few dashes would pass that limit. This may be a SE design issue.

Comment: How about calling it SQL-SSMS or MSSQL-SSMS?

Comment: or even "sqlserver-manag-studio", or something along those lines?

Comment: I'm fond of 'MSSQL-SSMS', with a synonym for the unreadable one. It can be arranged.

Comment: I suggest we call it "sql-server-management-std" (or "sql-server-manag-studio") which is consistent with all other SQL Server tags.

Comment: I vote for sql-server-mgmt-studio